# Feature engineering to prepare an XGBoost classifier

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, feature-engineering

Is there something in particular one should take into consideration when preparing data to a XGBoost Classifier? As it is tree based, it doesn't make any assumptions about data distribution like linear models does. However, does that mean we can't improve result by transform the distribution of the features?

If no, is it strictly an empirical question - try and evaluate - or is there some general guideline one could lean on?

Comment: It's a greedy algorithm looking at 1 variable at a time. if you know that your variables interact in certain ways then you should make those transformations.
How

Comment: You mean remove correlated variables is the main thing before feeding features to the model?

Comment: no I mean that if you think the decision depends on eg a ratio of two inputs, then you should enter the ratio as an extra input.